# Nodejs: Convert Promise-based API into synchronous API

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I have a Promise-based Nodejs-function that I want to call from a normal function (not an async function).

Therefore, I would like to create a wrapper function that is synchronous (returning `T` instead of returning `Promise<T>`).

How would you solve this with Nodejs?

Comment: Rewrite the function so it isn't promise based in the first place (which is likely to be impossible). Asynchronous code is usually asynchronous for good reasons.

Comment: You can write a function that returns `T` instead of `Promise<T>` but how will you call this function? You can't call it synchronously because it won't immediately return the required value.

Comment: I can call it synchronously because this is about a command-line task that would need to block anyways, regardless of whether I am using Promises or not.

Comment: Rewriting the promise-based function is not so easy because it is within a third-party-library.

Comment: Then don't use promises, just write normal blocking code. You can't make promise-based code to be blocking. It will be asynchronous no matter what you do.

Comment: As mentioned, the asynchronous code is provided by a third-party-library that is not so easy to rewrite. However, since Nodejs provides "synchronous" functions like "readFileSync", I thought that this is an easy API-conversion.